# How to store audio files paths in Realm database? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, audio, realm

I am trying to store audio files' paths, which are in app's directory, into Realm database. The problem is that the method for playing these audios isn't working:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var phraseVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhraseVC") as PhraseVC
    let phrase = phrases.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as Phrases
    phraseVC.audioName = phrase.phraseAudio
    navigationController?.pushViewController(phraseVC, animated: true)
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class PhraseVC: UIViewController {
 ...
 var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
 var audioName:String = ""

 @IBAction func playPhrase(sender: AnyObject) {
    var audioURL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(audioName, isDirectory: true)!
    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer?.stop()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL, error: &error)
    audioPlayer?.play()
 } 
}
```

How am I storing audios in database? I just wrote the names of audio files.
What can be the issue?

Comment: So it works when you set manually your stream path? Show us the string of your "audioName" path variable.

Comment: Are you making sure to store the entire file path, rather than just a file name?

Comment: @derdida I edited the code, you can look at

Comment: @segiddins I just wrote a file name in default.realm. The reason why I don't write the full path is that I am prepopulating the database, so I will use it for final version of app. And I also realized that when I run app the different devices in simulator have different, own default.realm file.